# Derived functors on 2 term exact sequence

Tags: category-theory, exact-sequence, abelian-categories, derived-functors

Suppose we have a not-short exact sequence 0 -> A -> B -> 0 in some abelian category. Now let us apply right exact functor F: F(A) -> F(B) -> 0.
So could I consider a left derived functor H to obtain the sequence
 ...-> H0(F(A)) -> H0(F(B)) -> F(A) -> F(B) -> 0?

I haven't seen this done with exact sequences with two non zero objects but was wondering if the concept would still hold.

Comment: If $0 \to A \to B \to 0$ is exact, then the map $A \to B$ in the middle is an isomorphism, hence so is the result of applying any functor to it.

Comment: Got it. But what if we had that the left map in F(A) -> F(B) -> 0 is surjective but not injective? Would it be reasonable to construct the same sequence as i mentioned above? H in this case is homology.

Comment: Again, if $0 \to A \to B \to 0$ is exact, then $A \to B$ is an isomorphism, so that can't happen.